# Loop does everything before asking user for a new input instead of just reasking as it should

Tags: java

I recently got assigned a homework to make code in a different language, the only language I have worked within python. What my code should do is ask the user for an input, and then first set it as the high, low and start calculating an average.

```
package hgp.pkg13.pkg16;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HGP1316 {
    //Declaration of variables
    static int Running_total = 0;
    static double Average = 0.0;
    static int User_input = 0;
    static double counter = 0.0 ;
    static int Highest_input = -1;
    static int Lowest_input = -1; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Intro Program (Optional)
    {
        System.out.println("This program will give you the highest, lowest, and average of the integers you \n"
          + "enter. To end enter a negative number ");       
    }

    //2. Ask user to enter a positive integer (or a negative integer to stop)
    //3. Record the user's input
    //4. Test the input >= 0
    while (User_input >=0){
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        Integer User_input;
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
        User_input = user_input.nextInt();
        //4a. If it is true that input >= 0
        if (User_input >= 0)
        {

            //4a1Add the input to "running total"
            Running_total = Running_total + User_input;
            //4a2. Increment "number of inputs counter"
            counter = counter + 1;  
            //4a3. Test if "number of inputs counter" is equal to 1
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                //4a31. If true, replace both "highest input" and "lowest input" with the input
                Highest_input = User_input;
                Lowest_input = User_input;
            }

            //4a5. If the input > "highest input" then replace "highest input" with input
           if (User_input > Highest_input)
           {
               Highest_input = User_input;
           }
           //4a6. If the input < "lowest input" then replace "lowest input" with input
           if (User_input < Lowest_input)
           {
               Lowest_input = User_input;
           }
           //4b. If false
           //4b1. Goto step 5
           else;
           {
               //5. Calculate average (formula: "running total" /"number of inputs counter" )
                Average = (Running_total / counter);
                //6. Display/communicate "highest input", "lowest input" and average
                System.out.println ("The Highest value entered was : "+ Highest_input);
                System.out.println ("The Lowest value entered was : " + Lowest_input);
                System.out.println("The Average of enteries was : "+ Average);
                //7. Terminate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I have now encountered is it goes through the whole loop instead of reasking for the users input. It is probably to do with my {} but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code - it's unreadable this way.

Comment: @JiriTousek I think i fixed the indentation of my code for you.

Comment: two things about this code: pls fix the indentation, this way it's completely incomprehensible. Why do you open a new `Scanner` in the loop?

Comment: @pckofwolfs nope, thats not better at all.

Comment: okay. I think I have fixed the indentation. To me it looks fine as I'm unsure where the indentation goes wrong. @Paul

Comment: @pckofwolfs i've corrected the indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are plenty of harmed coding conventions and best practices in this code, I will ignore most of them and focus on what is important in your case:

1. Your code will never get out of the loop. This is because you define `static int User_input = 0;` and then define a variable with the same name within the loop, which hides the static variable and stores the user input. However, it is the static variable that is being checked in the `while` condition.
2. You do not print where you're supposed to. Firstly, you have `else;` which basically does nothing, since it contains an empty statement. Afterwards you always execute the rest of the loop.

Here is the "fixed" code:

```
public class HGP1316 {
    static int Running_total = 0;
    static double Average = 0.0;
    static int User_input = 0;
    static double counter = 0.0 ;
    static int Highest_input = -1;
    static int Lowest_input = -1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            System.out.println("This program will give you the highest, lowest, and average of the integers you \n"
                    + "enter. To end enter a negative number ");
        }

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        while (User_input >= 0) {
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
            User_input = user_input.nextInt();

            if (User_input >= 0)
            {
                Running_total = Running_total + User_input;
                counter = counter + 1;
                if (counter == 1)
                {
                    Highest_input = User_input;
                    Lowest_input = User_input;
                }

                if (User_input > Highest_input)
                {
                    Highest_input = User_input;
                }

                if (User_input < Lowest_input)
                {
                    Lowest_input = User_input;
                }
            } else {
                Average = (Running_total / counter);
                System.out.println ("The Highest value entered was : "+ Highest_input);
                System.out.println ("The Lowest value entered was : " + Lowest_input);
                System.out.println("The Average of enteries was : "+ Average);
            }
        }
        user_input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go around getting it so the static variable isn't the one checking the loop and the non-static variable to be the loop checking variable?

Comment: You just remove the static variable and place the non-static one right before the loop.

Comment: Ahh I see it now. Thanks a lot with your help :D. Means a lot

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use the same variable name for local variables and class variables. Same for local variables and fields.

You have a local variable

```
Integer User_input;
```

and a class variable

```
static int User_input = 0;
```

In the while condition, you are using the class variable, which is always 0.
You do not need class variables in your example - use only local variables.

Easy check: you can prepend the class variables with the class name (HGP1316.User_input) - the code will compile correctly.

See more about [class variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. First, your variables are very similarly named so it's tough to debug. Second, your variable `User_input` should not be an instance of an `Integer` object, it should be an `int` primitive like such: `static int User_input = 0`

Third, you recreate the scanner variable `user_input` on each iteration of your while loop. The scanner should be declared a single time prior to the loop as such:

```
Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (...)
{
    // get user input
}
```

Fourth, having the while-loop check is `User_input >= 0` AND having an if-statement check the same thing is redundant. Instead, do...

```
Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (input_scanner.hasNext())
{
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    User_input = input_scanner.nextInt();

    if (User_input >= 0)
    { 
        // hanlde input
    }
}
```

Fifth, even if the counter, if zero, the if-statements after your check are still used, which is unnecessary. To fix, use `else if` and `else` statements like so:

```
if (counter == 1)
{
    Highest_input = User_input;
    Lowest_input = User_input; 
}
else if (User_input > Highest_input)
{
    Highest_input = User_input;
}
else if (User_input < Lowest_input)
{
    Lowest_input = User_input;
}
```

Sixth, you need to ultimately break out of your loop when a user inputs a negative number, currently, you just don't include the number in your average calculation but your while-loop still runs! (also you have a syntax error: `else;` should just be `else`).

```
else
{
    Average = (Running_total / counter);
    System.out.println ("The Highest value entered was : "+ Highest_input);
    System.out.println ("The Lowest value entered was : " + Lowest_input);
    System.out.println("The Average of enteries was : "+ Average);

    break;
}
```

Seventh, and last, you need to close your scanner: `input_scanner.close()`

Here is the final, working code after you make all of the above fixes:

```
static int Running_total = 0;
static double Average = 0.0;
static int User_input = 0;
static double counter = 0.0 ;
static int Highest_input = -1;
static int Lowest_input = -1; 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("This program will give you the highest, lowest, and average of the integers you \n"
      + "enter. To end enter a negative number ");

    Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    while (input_scanner.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
        User_input = input_scanner.nextInt();
        if (User_input >= 0)
        {
            Running_total = Running_total + User_input;
            counter = counter + 1; 
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                Highest_input = User_input;
                Lowest_input = User_input;
            }
            else if (User_input > Highest_input)
            {
                Highest_input = User_input;
            }
            else if (User_input < Lowest_input)
            {
                Lowest_input = User_input;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Average = (Running_total / counter);
            System.out.println ("The Highest value entered was : "+ Highest_input);
            System.out.println ("The Lowest value entered was : " + Lowest_input);
            System.out.println("The Average of enteries was : "+ Average);
            break;
        }
    }
    input_scanner.close();
}
```